# yii Forms returns error, parameter is not defined

Tags: php, yii, yii-chtml

I have Settings controller like

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $model = new SettingsForm;

    if(isset($_POST['SettingsForm'])) {
        if($model->validate()) {
            //
        }
    }

    $this->render('index', array('model' => $model));
}
```

and in settings view:

```
<?php
$form = $this->beginWidget(
    'CActiveForm', array(
       'id' => 'settings-form',
       'enableClientValidation' => true,
       'clientOptions' => array(
           'validateOnSubmit' => true,
       ),
));
?>
<div class="form-group">
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'meta_keywords'); ?>
<?php echo $form->textField($model, 'meta_keywords', array('class' => 'form-control', 'value' => Yii::app()->config->get('meta_keywords'), 'placeholder' => 'Ключевые слова и фразы через запятую')); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model, 'meta_keywords', array('class' => 'text-danger')); ?>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'main_page'); ?>
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'main_page', $model->getPages()); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model, 'main_page', array('class' => 'text-danger')); ?>
</div>
```

function getPages in SettingsForm model:

```
public function getPages() {
        return array(
            0 => 'Nothing'
        );
    }
```

This code returns error:

> Property "SettingsForm.main_page" is not defined.

But all previos elements Yii created successfully and don't return any error =\

Answer (score 0):

In your `SettingsForm` model is `main_page` defined in the `rules` method? i.e.

```
public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        array( ... 'main_page', ...),
        ...
    );
}
```

Comment: hmm... and `var_dump($model->main_page)` returns anything, or does that return an error too? You could also try `array('main_page', 'safe')` in the rules array too, just to see if it's an issue with the booleanValidator?

Comment: @heeeej, still please post in question (as update) the whole model validation rules.

Answer (score 0):

### Updated

> class SettingsForm extends CFormModel

Still do it. Look at [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/161/understanding-safe-validation-rules/#hh0) and [here (rus)](http://phptime.ru/yii/perevod-pravilo-validacii-safe-dlya-teh-kto-v-tanke.html).

```
public function rules()
{        
    return array(
        array('site_name, charset, meta_description, meta_keywords', 'required'),
        array('main_page', 'boolean'),
        array('site_name, charset, meta_description, meta_keywords, main_page', 'safe'),
    );
}
```

Comment: i did echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'main_page', array(0 => 'nothing')); and.... NOTHING +)

Comment: @heeeej, how about in dropdown you just put `$form->dropDownList($model, 'main_page', array(0=>'smth'))` will it work?

Comment: @heeeej, also, do you need ClientValidation to be ON? Try to turn it off: `'enableClientValidation' => false,` since you validate in server and in dropdown nothing is inputed from outside.

Comment: @heeeej, still would you post in your question (as update) the whole model validation rules like these: `public function rules()
 {
  return array(
   array('userId, email', 'required'),...
`

Comment: I posted.. I called all fields =(

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
     * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(
            array('site_name, charset, meta_description, meta_keywords', 'required'),
            array('main_page', 'boolean')
        );
    }
```

Comment: sure, you did not define `array('site_name, charset, meta_description, meta_keywords, main_page', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),` as the last line in this array. So they are not SAFE for storing in AR and DB. Do it.

Answer (score 0):

Pfffff....
I just forgot call variable in model $main_page...

```
class SettingsForm extends CFormModel
{
    public $site_name;
    public $charset;
    public $meta_description;
    public $meta_keywords;
    public $main_page;

..
}
```